# Safety of named pipes

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I'm wondering how safe is data transfer via named pipes using System.IO.Pipes (without WCF)

Is it required to check e.g. md5 sum after data transfer or maybe it would be better idea to implement transactions for it and if so is there any straight way for it without using P/Invoke to TransactNamedPipe (I guess there is no wrapper in .net)?

Or maybe TCP is just safier than named pipes?

EDIT:

Additionally:

What I really have in mind is what will happen if server or client crash - what about delivery then?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? What is your concern? Data loss?

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering if I can be sure data will be delivered completely

Comment: Yes. Just as sure as you can be with a file or a TCP connection.  Checksumming the data after you read it is unnecessary.

Comment: What can be TransactNamedPipe purpose then? In fact there are even transactional ntfs methods

Comment: [Transactions on Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365789.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I have read that, whats why I got into question, is traditional pipe completely safe if transactional one has been created

Comment: But there doesn't seem to be any such thing as a "transactional pipe". They're still just created as usual, `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE`. The only difference is the call to `TransactNamedPipe`. And even that says *nothing* about being "transactional" in the sense of rollback, just that you can read and write in one operation.

Comment: Ah ok, I was misleaded by its name, thank you for explanation

Comment: What I really have in mind is what will happen if server or client crash - what about delivery then?

Comment: Ok, I guess I need to just to assume that if there is no server response it means it failed

Answer (score 0):

Named pipes gives you

- communication channel with ACL (Access Control List) between 2 processes on same/different machines (unlike TCP where you need to secure access to the channel yourself)
- Name of the channel (similar to TCP ports), but with eseentially no restrictions on numer of names
- With trasactions gives write+read operation that will atomically succeed/failes (with TCP you need to implement such operation it yourself).

Both give you guaranteed delivery of the data.

Comment: With trasactions gives write+read operation <- how can I use use it with transactions?

Comment: Do you mean TransactNamedPipe or something else?

Comment: @user1121956 yes,  Jonathon Reinhart bove discussed the behavior (not DB-kind of transactions, just single write+read as atomic operation).